# Pygame text not appearing

Tags: python, text, pygame

I have made a pong game in python but I've been watching so many tutorials on how to add text. I want a score counter for the player but every tutorial I try I do not get any errors but I get no text on the screen. If you know of any way to fix this or notice any mistakes please let me know. By the way this is my first time coding in this module.

```py
import pygame, random

pygame.font.init()

opponent_score = 0
player_score = 0


smallfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

def draw_playscore():
    text = smallfont.render("Score: " + str(player_score), True, 255, 255, 255)
    screen.blit(text, [250 , 250])

def ball_animation():
    global opponent_score
    global player_score
    global ball_speed_x, ball_speed_y

    ball.x += ball_speed_x
    ball.y += ball_speed_y

    if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        ball_speed_y *= -1
    if ball.left <=0:
        ball_restart()
        player_score +=1
    elif ball.right >= SCREEN_WIDTH:
        ball_restart()
        opponent_score +=1


    if ball.colliderect(player) or ball.colliderect(opponent):
        ball_speed_x *= -1

def player_animation():
    player.y += player_speed
    if player.top <= 0:
        player.top = 0
    if player.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        player.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

def opponent_animation():
    if opponent.top < ball.y:
        opponent.top += opponent_speed
    if opponent.bottom > ball.y:
        opponent.bottom -= opponent_speed
    if opponent.top <= 0:
        opponent.top = 0
    if opponent.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        opponent.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

def ball_restart():
    global ball_speed_x, ball_speed_y
    ball.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)
    ball_speed_y *= random.choice((1,-1))

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

ball = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 15, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 -15, 30, 30)
player = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH -20, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 -70, 10, 140)
opponent = pygame.Rect(10, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 -70, 10, 140)

bg_color = pygame.Color('grey12')
light_grey = (200,200,200)

ball_speed_x = 5
ball_speed_y = 5
player_speed = 0
opponent_speed = 7


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_speed +=2
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_speed -=2
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_speed =0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_speed =0

    ball_animation()
    player_animation()
    opponent_animation()
    draw_playscore()

    screen.fill(bg_color)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, opponent)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, light_grey, ball)
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen, light_grey, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2,0), (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT))




    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
if opponent_score > player_score:
    print("The opponent won with " + str(opponent_score - player_score) + " more than you!")
elif player_score > opponent_score:
    print("You Won With a " + str(player_score - opponent_score) + " point difference! Congrats!")
elif player_score == opponent_score:
    print("Its a tie!")
print("You got " + str(player_score) + " points!")
print ("The Opponent got " + str(opponent_score) + " points!")
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) fill a Surface with a solid color and overlays everything that was drawn before. [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) updates the screen. Everything that is drawn after the screen is cleared and before the screen is updated is visible. Everything else is not visible. You have to call `draw_playscore` after clearing the background with `screen.fill(bg_color)`:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    ball_animation()
    player_animation()
    opponent_animation()
    # draw_playscore()          <-- DELETE

    screen.fill(bg_color)

    draw_playscore()          # <-- INSERT

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, light_grey, opponent)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, light_grey, ball)
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen, light_grey, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2,0), (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    pygame.display.update()
```